# Batch script to create home home directories from list of names

Tags: scripting, batch

I'm trying to create a home directories with permissions from a text file.  I can only get the batch file to run the first line.  Can anyone tell me why?

I initiate the scripts by running go.bat as administrator.

**go.bat**

```
@echo
for /f %%a in (users1.txt) do call test.bat %%a
```

**test.bat**

```
@echo off
m:
cd \
mkdir %1
icacls %1 /grant %1:(OI)(CI)M 

cd %1

mkdir public
icacls public /inheritance:d
icacls public / All:(OI)(CI)(RD)
icacls public /grant All:(OI)(CI)R

mkdir private
icacls private /inheritance:d
icacls private /remove All

cd \
```

**users1.txt**

```
user1
user2
user3
```

Comment: Is PowerShell an option here? Batch scripts are dead dead dead.

Comment: Not familiar with powershell as much, but let me know what you're thinking and I'll try it out for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use your familiar `icacls` commands with PowerShell looping as an "introduction" to PowerShell.

Something like this should do it

```
Get-Content C:\users.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $User = $_
    $WorkingPath = "M:\" + "$User"
    mkdir $WorkingPath

    icacls $WorkingPath /grant $User:(OI)(CI)M 

    $Public = "$WorkingPath" + "public"
    mkdir $Public
    icacls $Public /inheritance:d
    icacls $Public / All:(OI)(CI)(RD)
    icacls $Public /grant All:(OI)(CI)R

    $Private = "$WorkingPath" + "private"
    mkdir $Private
    icacls $Private /inheritance:d
    icacls $Private /remove All
}
```

There's `Get-ACL` and `Set-ACL` for working with permissions in PowerShell, as well as replacements for `mkdir` and similar commands, but this way you can *ease* into using it.

Comment: I wish I could give more than +1. Good answer, good advice of "start using PowerShell", good advice of "ease into it slowly". Steven - get into PowerShell as quick as you can. It is about a million times more powerful as batch files and only about 50% harder to learn.

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks for your help.  I will try this out!

Comment: Note that I didn't actually run the commands, I took the icacls statements from your script. But it's a good outline

Comment: Yeah, I tried to run it as is and the results weren't as expected.  That's okay though, this will be a good first step to learning.